# Why is JQuery.Datatable not rendering and also not giving an error?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is the entire code in my cshtml view file.

I get a good webpage with a formatted table.

BUT it is not being formatted by JQuery.Datatable. I can remove all the script lines and it still looks the same.

WHat might I be doing wrong. I do not get any build errors relating to JQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Employee Index Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js">
    </script>

    <script >
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
                } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Employee Index Page</h1>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Symbol</th>
                    <th>ActualPosition</th>
                    <th>AccountIdent</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @{
                    var categories = (DataTable)ViewData["MyData"];

                    foreach (DataRow item in categories.Rows)
                    {
                        string symbol = item.Field<string>("Symbol");
                        string actualPositionText = item.Field<long>("ActualPosition").ToString();
                        string accountIdent = item.Field<string>("AccountIdent");

                        <tr>
                            <td>@symbol </td>
                            <td>@actualPositionText</td>
                            <td>@accountIdent </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            <tbody>
        </table>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the browser is pulling down the dataTable scripts? Do you see any errors in the debugger console?

Comment: Can you confirm that both datatables and jQuery are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

your view missed the CSS file

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>Employee Index Page</title>
   <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: No that didn't help

Comment: Put the render code at the end of the body not in head <script > $(document).ready(function() { $('#example').DataTable(); } ); </script>

Comment: Again, it does not make any difference. I am really stuck

Comment: Make sure your code to instantiate datatable is called when the page if fully loaded. I had this problem on my application,  it was caused by flash of unstyled content (FOUC).

Comment: @Aim How do I ensure that?

Comment: @MainMoon use window.load

Comment: Do you mean $('#Index').load(); Where my View is called Index.cshtml. Doesn't seem to help

Comment: $( window ).load(function() {

$('#example').DataTable();});

Comment: @ManInMoon  $(window).bind("load", function() {  $('#example').DataTable();  })

Note: This will only solve the problem when your application has FOUC, which means there are some elements which are shortly displayed(unstyled) before their respective css has styled them.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce this, but I've haven't been able to do so.

Please take a look at [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C8WQsb). It contains the same code of your sample, the only difference is that jquery and datatable scripts are been referenced from CDN, and it works!

So, I'm thinking you might have some issues with the local files you're serving or something like that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try add the dataTables example html to your page to rule out any mvc or HTML syntax errrors.